# /dev/sda4/ on USB stick isn't available after formatting. 'Discs' shows the following:

Tags: partition, mkdir, mkfs

size: 58 GB
contents:  unknown
device: /dev/sda4
partition type: basic data
When I ran the format, I selected the type which I expected result in type of Linux.
I found a similar issue from 2019, but fdisk wouldn't run the solution.
The file type may be suitable, but I haven't been able to run 'mkdir' on the partition.
'Files' doesn't see the partition under "Other Locations".
Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mkdir on a partition.

You need to format (that's not the same as assignment of a partition type) it and mount it first